Fedora 39 VM fails to boot in UEFI mode
I am running Fedora 39 on macOS via UTM. It is set to UEFI for boot management. Until recently, it would bring up the VM's internal boot loader (grub2) just fine, but recently it started failing with the message: Synchronous Exception at <some address> (for reasons I don't understand yet.)
Here is the EFI mapping of the "broken state":

Through trial and error I realized that as soon as an ISO is mounted and a "CD-ROM" block device exists (I used the Fedora 40 live ISO), the Fedora entry starts working again. However, I have to reach it via the EFI shell for this to work:

I don't understand what exactly is broken. The only difference I can see is that when the ISO is mounted, the volume name of the boot partition in the EFI boot sequence changes to FS1 instead of FS0 (because then, the "CD ROM" device will be FS0):

I do not really understand where EFI ends and GRUB starts, to be honest. Could someone help me understand what could be broken here and how to fix it? I also looked at https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/latest/system-administrators-guide/kernel-module-driver-configuration/Working_with_the_GRUB_2_Boot_Loader/#sec-Reinstalling_GRUB_2 but I was afraid of rm -f-ing anything from /boot and anyway, the fact that running the .efi executables directly from /boot works when the iso is mounted suggests to me it's not a grub config issue? I could be wrong!
